# How do I group error logs from DB to display the split of error message dynamically

Tags: sql-server, algorithm

I have a error log table in SQL Server that contains a ID and an corresponding error message. The log table is populated by an different service during the loading process and the error messages are not modifiable. The log table looks something like this.

```
 ID | Error Messsage
101 | 101 failed due to a error in xxx module.
102 | 102 failed due to a error in xxx module.
101 | Mapping for column xyz missing for 101
102 | Mapping for column xyz missing for 102
103 | Mapping for column xyz missing for 103
```

I want to group this by the type of error message and display the split of the error message along with it's count. Which would look something like this

```
      Error Message                 | Count
Failed due to a error in xxx module | 2
Mapping for column xyz missing      | 3
```

Currently, I am implementing this with a stored procedure using the `like` operator where I switch through the known error types and increment it's count. One big issue with this is when a unknown type of error is encountered the procedure fails and the same error type gets displayed multiple times with only the ID changing.

I have seen Google play store app reviews being grouped which looked similar to this although a lot more complex. This looked like an interesting problem to solve with a similar approach. But I have no idea on how to proceed with this. Any links or approaches to solve this problem or an explanation of this will or won't work would  be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new table: ErrorType:

```
TypeID | Message
 1     | {0} failed due to a error in xxx module.
 2     | Mapping for column xyz missing for {0}
```

And change your log table and logging code to use the ErrorType:

```
 ID | TypeID
101 | 1
102 | 1
101 | 2
102 | 2
103 | 2
```

And suddenly now you have something you can group by easily. Additionally, it's still trivial to write a query that produced your original messages:

```
select l.ID, Replace(t.Message, '{0}', l.ID) As Message
from ErrorLogs l
inner join ErrorTypes t on t.TypeId = l.TypeID
```

Of course, the `{0}` placeholder was chosen for compatibility with .Net's `String.Format()` method, so you could easily wait to do your own substitution on the client, and even choose your own message placeholder if you're not using .Net.

What really makes this nice, though, is the ability to include additional placeholders in the future, where you might want to re-use these ErrorTypes for more than one module/column. I get the sense you **already** have this problem, or you wouldn't need to talk about a `LIKE` operation in the question:

```
TypeID | Message
 1     | {0} failed due to a error in {1} module.
 2     | Mapping for column {1} missing for {0}
```

```
 ID | TypeID | SupplementalData
101 | 1      |   xxx
102 | 1      |   xxx
101 | 2      |   xyz
102 | 2      |   xyz
103 | 2      |   aaa
```

```
select l.ID,
    Replace(Replace(t.Message, '{0}', l.ID), '{1}', l.SupplementalData) As Message
from ErrorLogs l
inner join ErrorTypes t on t.TypeId = l.TypeID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joel. But like I mentioned modifying the error log table or the format of the error message can't be done as I don't have access to that code. So if I wanted to build the ErrorType table from the log table  I would still have to use the like operator right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `REPLACE()` function to remove the string of characters equal to the ID column for the same row.

You can uses spaces to make sure you only remove entire IDs and not partial ones:

```
REPLACE(' '+[Error Message]+' ',' '+CAST([ID] AS varchar(31))+' ',' ')
```